# Django QuerySet querying or filtering "Odd" and/or "Even" value in a particular field

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-queryset

```
# Example
from django.db import models

class ParkingLot(models.Model):
    lot_number = models.IntegerField()
    is_reserved = models.BooleanField()
```

I'm interested in Odd xor Even `lot_number`. 
What's the recommended way to filter that in Django?

I've posted some answer below.

---

### Challenge

Does anyone know if we can use a direct comparison something like `F('lot_number') % 2 == 0` technique?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Django >1.8 you could use [F() expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions):

```
# ParkingLots with even numbered lot_numbers
ParkingLot.objects.annotate(odd=F('lot_number') % 2).filter(odd=False)  

# ParkingLots with odd numbered lot_numbers
ParkingLot.objects.annotate(odd=F('lot_number') % 2).filter(odd=True)
```

This won't work in older versions of Django though.

Comment: Oh, exactly... This is what i've been looking for... Thanks @jproffitt ... You complete the final answer :D

Answer (score 3):

This query can be done in Database Layer.

```
even_lots = ParkingLot.objects.filter(id__iregex='^\d*[02468]$') # Hit Database
odd_lots = ParkingLot.objects.filter(id__iregex='^\d*[13579]$') # Hit Database
```

Behind the scene, the even queryset will create the following SQL Query.

```
SELECT *
FROM parkinglot
WHERE id REGEXP '^\d*[02468]$'
```

Provided that we are interested in odd `XOR` even. I believed this should be the preferred method. However, I'm not sure, but heard that regex is slow.

### Update

Check @jproffitt, That should be the best.

Answer (score -1):

This query can be done in Python level.

```
parking_lots = list(ParkingLot.objects.all()) # Hit Database once
odd_lots = parking_lots[0::2]
even_lots = parking_lots[1::2]
```