# how can i define User Groups and permissions on django to control a news model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

i have News model. i want to manage news by users who belongs from these Groups?

```
class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text="Short title of news")
    content = models.TextField(blank=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

how can i define these user permissions?

```
Users Groups        Permissions

Reporters       # create a news
CopyEditors     # read and update
Poducers        # read, update, aprove and revoke
Rundown         # list of aproved articles
Anchors         # read only aproved articles
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add custom permissions into your model. 
Some permissions already defined  which are add,delete,change and delete.But here you need to add custom permissions.

```
class News(models.Model):

  title = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text="Short title of news")
  content = models.TextField(blank=True)
  author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
  status = models.BooleanField(default=True)


  class Meta:
     permissions = (
        ('custom_permission', 'title goes here'),

    )
```

**Must read these**

[Assign object permissions](https://django-guardian.readthedocs.io/en/stable/userguide/assign.html)

[Model and Permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30156375/model-and-permissions)

[Add a custom permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876424/add-a-custom-permission-to-a-user)